# mysql is not comparing NULL as a blank value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

MySQLi is not comparing NULL as a blank value.

In my case:

```
if($Id == 1) {
    $cond = " AND my_field != '' ";
} elseif ($Id == 2){
    $cond = " AND my_field = '' ";
}
```

While executing a mysql statement having `!=''` in `WHERE` condition the result set is not exact opposite to the result-set having `=''` in WHERE condition. 
and here `!=''` statement perfectly working fine.

But when i put this condition in `elseif` it's working fine.

```
elseif ($Id == 2){
   $cond = " AND my_field IS NULL ";
}
```

Comment: Solution : 
**NULL. Every time.** 
The result of comparing anything to NULL, even itself, is always, always NULL. A comparison to NULL is never true or false. Since NULL can never be equal to any value, it can never be unequal, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the reason behind the query not returning proper result set is that it is comparing '' with NULL stored in the database. But any comparison with NULL in MySQL returns NULL which is neither true nor false. Hence it always discards the records of NULL values regardless of the operator used ie = or !=.

Check this query and you will be able understand it more clearly

`SELECT 0 IS NULL , 0 IS NOT NULL , '' IS NULL , '' IS NOT NULL, NULL != NULL, NULL = NULL, NULL != '', NULL = ''`

Comment: thanks for the solution , it means NULL is working as `Three-valued logic` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic

Comment: Yes you got it right.  Hope now you will not face any problem with NULL in MySQL.

Answer (score 5):

NULL is not the same as an empty string in MySQL. Try

```
"AND (orders.user_id = '' OR orders.user_id IS NULL)"
```

Comment: Because you're looking for anything with a value, which does not include NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

Null is special case value in SQL in general, you can not compare NULL like this `id=null , id != null` but `id is null , id is not null` you can have a look on these:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: yeah exactly that what i am asking. 
if it's working with  **!=''**  then why it's NOT working with **=''**
and this is the same scenario, 
i have solution that if i put **IS NULL** & **IS NOT NULL** will work, thanks :)